# Consuming WCF Duplex Service from ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, duplex

I have a WCF duplex service that sends messages to several clients. This part is working good but the thing I need to do is starting the process from an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have a UI that is using this API and when the user submits the form in UI the API needs to call the WCF duplex service and this service will distribute the related data to clients who are connected to this service. Since I can't use `WSDualHttpBinding` class in ASP.NET Core because of the `System.ServiceModel` v4.2.

The real question is how can I trigger the process (WCF duplex) from ASP.NET Core? I don't need to create a channel between ASP.NET Core and WCF duplex since I don't need a callback in the ASP.NET Core project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no WCF implementation in .net core. If you have started development from scratch on net core, then start working through web sockets. In this case, you can save duplex communication.

Comment: Actually there is (in the link below) but not for duplex
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: This implementation is necessary only for working with SOAP services. Services and a different type of behavior will not work. You cannot connect a half-duplex service over TCP

Comment: WCF for dot net core only works for clients... WCF Host is not supported... I wasted a whole day on this!